# How To Split List Evenly/

Tags: c#

This is what i cam doing right now

```
items = new List<TableItem> ();
            items.Add (new TableItem (){ name = "Apple" });
            items.Add (new TableItem (){ name = "Pear" });
            items.Add (new TableItem (){ name = "Shoe" });
            items.Add (new TableItem (){ name = "Cake" });
            items.Add (new TableItem (){ name = "Vodka" });
            items.Add (new TableItem (){ name = "Alize" });
            items.Add (new TableItem (){ name = "Alizeee" });
            ........
            ........
            ........
```

This is what i am doing right now, with this way one item is missing because its odd number for the count, the list will be populated from a api so there could be any number of items added to the list

```
            int number = items.Count;
            int number2 = number / 2;

            List<TableItem> firstList = items.GetRange(0, number2);
            List<TableItem> secondList = items.GetRange(number2, number2);


            listView1.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, firstList);
            listView2.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter (this, secondList);
```

Comment: What do you mean, when you say that you want to split the list evenly? how many sub-lists do you expect for a given number of items in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 1 to the length of your second list if the count is odd:

```
        int number = items.Count;
        int number2 = number / 2;

        List<TableItem> firstList = items.GetRange(0, number2);
        List<TableItem> secondList = items.GetRange(number2, number % 2 == 0? number2 : number2 + 1);


        listView1.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, firstList);
        listView2.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter (this, secondList);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you expect odd lists then
you should use [Math.Ceil](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-ceiling) or [Math.Floor](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-floor) to select the middle number based on your requirement
so if your list contains 5 elements then

```
number = Math.Ceil(5/2) // will return 3;
number = Math.Floor(5/2) // will return 2
```

Comment: I tested it because I wasn't sure if it would compute correctly or even compile (above text doesn't). It works when you use `Math.Ceiling(5 / 2.0)` or `Math.Floor(5/2.0)`

Comment: Even after edit it would end with `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Floor(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Floor(double)'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
var half = items.Count() / 2;
var firstList = items.Take(half).ToList();
var secondList = items.Skip(half).ToList()
```